# Is the video game UNO haram not the real life game

Tags: halal-haram, sin, game, doubts

I use to play a video games called “uno” the card game but in a video game you can turn off the music but when you play a card down it has like an effect and I’m wondering if it’s halal look up a gameplay of the video game before you answer the question  if you do not know what it is. Thank you may Allah reward you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No card game is haram as long as it doesn't involve betting/gambling or anything haram, like drink alcohol for this many points or hit the guy next to you to get this many points.

People say card games are haram because it is the main source for betting/gambling, but the card game itself is not haram only gambling/betting.

But card game which involves bank and interest  or similar haram things is better avoided. Although it is not real and just game it is not good to do haram even for fake.